# How to retrieve the execution status of ansible module?

Tags: docker, ansible, docker-container, ansible-tower

Below the docker_container module:

```
- name: Create a data container
  docker_container:
    name: mydeploycontainer
    image: 1111112222.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/someteam/app-deploy:v.1
    env:
      name1: "value1"
      name2: "value2"
      name3: "value3"
```

---

we are running this in tower

How to retrieve the execution status of `docker_container` module? on stdout..

Comment: Does [the return value of the `docker_container` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/docker_container_module.html#return-values) have what you need?  Or [`docker_container_info`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/docker_container_info_module.html#docker-container-info-module)?

Comment: @DavidMaze return value of container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register the task result to a specific variable, however the `docker_container` module also creates an `ansible_facts` variable aptly called `docker_container`

So using this variable, you can return various values, for example:

```
  - debug:
      var: docker_container.State.ExitCode

  - debug:
      var: docker_container.State.Status

  - debug:
      var: docker_container.Output
```

Note that if you want to see the stdout of the container using `docker_container.Output`, then you need to add the `detach` argument to your task. For example:

```
  - name: Create a data container
    docker_container:
      name: mydeploycontainer
      image: 1111112222.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/someteam/app-deploy:v.1
      env:
        name1: "value1"
        name2: "value2"
        name3: "value3"
      detach: false
    register: mydeploycontainer_result
```

The example above also shows how to register the task result to a variable named `mydeploycontainer_result`. This would allow you to save the result of multiple container deployments.